Error with Texture File and Mod Metadata When Registering Item in Minecraft Mod Using NeoForge 1.21
I'm currently developing a Minecraft mod using NeoForge, and I've encountered an issue when registering a custom item. After adding my texture file for the item, I receive the following error when trying to run the client:
Execution failed for task ':generateModMetadata'. 
Could not copy file 'C:\Users\casro\Documents\Minecraft Modding\NeoForge\NeoForge-FalloutMc\src\main\templates\assets\falloutmc\texures\item\nuka_cola.png' to 'C:\Users\casro\Documents\Minecraft Modding\NeoForge\NeoForge-FalloutMc\build\generated\sources\modMetadata\assets\falloutmc\texures\item\nuka_cola.png'.Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
 SimpleTemplateScript30.groovy: 8: token recognition error at: '\t' @ line 8, column 38.
    {3D� ��#��!��-i�l�����a�e�{�m�a���$   �R.���ɇ�d#�J8?;��,�]'I�V�$�c������&�f�u�=����s�j��W(�� �^�ʔ��������i���D�K�r*U����c}�;I�_�(�V#GA��0���C7�[���� �K���tS��a��]Z9�%iƢ��/)�8�3Ay��ݺ�a�[��~5����    IEND�B`�""");
                                         ^

Additionally, I noticed that my project directory contains a templates folder instead of a resources folder. When I rename the templates folder to resources, the client runs, but I encounter this new error:
File C:\Users\********\Documents\Minecraft Modding\NeoForge\NeoForge-FalloutMc\build\classes\java\main is not a valid mod file
com.electronwill.nightconfig.core.io.ParsingException: Invalid bare key: '${mod_id}'

Here is the screen i get when i renamed the templates folder to resources:

I've attached the full crash report and latest log here: Crash-Report and Latest Log
Maybe these parts of my code might help:
(Main mod file) FalloutMc.java:
package net.cassis2310.falloutmc;

import net.cassis2310.falloutmc.item.ModItems;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;

import net.neoforged.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.neoforged.bus.api.IEventBus;
import net.neoforged.bus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.neoforged.fml.ModContainer;
import net.neoforged.fml.common.EventBusSubscriber;
import net.neoforged.fml.common.Mod;
import net.neoforged.fml.config.ModConfig;
import net.neoforged.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.neoforged.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.neoforged.neoforge.common.NeoForge;
import net.neoforged.neoforge.event.BuildCreativeModeTabContentsEvent;
import net.neoforged.neoforge.event.server.ServerStartingEvent;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/neoforge.mods.toml file
@Mod(FalloutMc.MOD_ID)
public class FalloutMc
{
    public static final String MOD_ID = "falloutmc";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();

    // The constructor for the mod class is the first code that is run when your mod is loaded.
    // FML will recognize some parameter types like IEventBus or ModContainer and pass them in automatically.
    public FalloutMc(IEventBus modEventBus, ModContainer modContainer)
    {
        // Register the commonSetup method for modloading
        modEventBus.addListener(this::commonSetup);

        // Register ourselves for server and other game events we're interested in.
        // Note that this is necessary if and only if we want *this* class (ExampleMod) to respond directly to events.
        // Don't add this line if there are no @SubscribeEvent-annotated functions in this class, like onServerStarting() below.
        NeoForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);

        ModItems.register(modEventBus);

        // Register the item to a creative tab
        modEventBus.addListener(this::addCreative);

        // Register our mod's ModConfigSpec so that FML can create and load the config file for us
        modContainer.registerConfig(ModConfig.Type.COMMON, Config.SPEC);
    }

    private void commonSetup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event)
    {
        //
    }

    // Add the example block item to the building blocks tab
    private void addCreative(BuildCreativeModeTabContentsEvent event)
    {
        //
    }

    // You can use SubscribeEvent and let the Event Bus discover methods to call
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onServerStarting(ServerStartingEvent event)
    {
        //;
    }

    // You can use EventBusSubscriber to automatically register all static methods in the class annotated with @SubscribeEvent
    @EventBusSubscriber(modid = MOD_ID, bus = EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD, value = Dist.CLIENT)
    public static class ClientModEvents
    {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onClientSetup(FMLClientSetupEvent event)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}

(Registry) ModItems.java:
package net.cassis2310.falloutmc.item;

import net.cassis2310.falloutmc.FalloutMc;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.neoforged.bus.api.IEventBus;
import net.neoforged.neoforge.registries.DeferredItem;
import net.neoforged.neoforge.registries.DeferredRegister;

public class ModItems {
    public static final DeferredRegister.Items ITEMS = DeferredRegister.createItems(FalloutMc.MOD_ID);

    public static final DeferredItem<Item> NUKA_COLA = ITEMS.register("nuka_cola",
            () -> new Item(new Item.Properties()));

    public static void register(IEventBus eventBus) {
        ITEMS.register(eventBus);
    }
}

(Item Model) nuka_cola.json:
{
  "parent": "minecraft:item/generated",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "falloutmc:item/nuka_cola"
  }
}

I have am using the latest ModDevGradle MDK from NeoForge.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

It looks like your project is not exported correctly, how do you export it at the moment ?

Hey Lanfix, what do you mean by not exported correctly. I kept everything default, everything goes good until I place a texture in the templates folder.

It was working before adding textures ?

Don't put assets and data in the templates folder, use the resources folder

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
